# Vue.Js - Add data to an array and assigning to the props (help)

Tags: html, vue.js

i have a problem, that i want to make my component could add new sidebar menu item each item user clickin an add button. so basically my component should appear when user defining their own sidebar menu item.

here's the vue js code i've write:

```js
Vue.component('sb-menu-item', {
   props: ['attrib'],
   template: '<a class="item"><i  class="{{attrib.icon}} icon"></i>{{attrib.name}}</a>'
});

new Vue({
    el: '#sb-list',
    data: {
        itemsProp: [{icon: 'calendar icon', name: 'history'}],
        newItems: [{icon: '', name: ''}]
    },
    methods: {
        addItem: function (){
            this.itemsProp.push({icon: this.newItems.icon, name: this.newItems.name});
            // this.itemsProp.name.push(this.attrib.name);
            this.newItems = [];
        },
        delItem: function (){
            this.itemsProp.pop();
        }
    }
});
```

```html
 <div class="ui top attached menu">
        <a class="item">
            <i class="sidebar icon"></i>
            <i class="right chevron icon"></i>
            Menu
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="ui bottom attached segment pushable" id="sb-list">
        <div class="ui visible left vertical sidebar menu" >
            <a class="item">
                <i class="home icon"></i>
                Dashboard
            </a>
            <a class="item">
                <i class="user icon"></i>
                Account
            </a>
            <sb-menu-item v-for="item in itemsProp" v-bind:attrib="item" v-model="itemsProp"></sb-menu-item>
        </div>
    <div class="pusher">
        <div class="ui basic teal segment">
            <h3 class="ui header">Insert New Sidebar Items</h3>
            <hr />
            <form class="ui tiny teal form compact raised padded segment">
                <div class="field">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Item Name" v-model="newItems.name">
                </div>
                <div class="field">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="icon name" v-model="newItems.icon">
                </div>
                <button class="ui medium teal float button" v-on:click="addItem"><i class="cubes icon"></i>  Make It!</button>
                <button class="ui medium red float button" v-on:click="delItem"><i class="trash icon"></i>Pop Last Menu! Now!</button>
            </form>
            
            <p></p>
            <div class="ui medium teal raised padded segment">{{$data | json}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

this codes work, but each time i click the add button it has been added their own sidebar menu item that i've defined from the forms, and in a seconds those item disappear. (i am using semanticUI though)

sorry for my bad english and explanation. i hope u can understand this, thanks!

Comment: Can you add code of sb-menu-item, and better if you can create a fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 potential issues. I will try to add a jsFiddle later maybe.
First of all I would make the `newItem` and object instead of an array.
Second issue is the `v-model` in the `sb-menu-item` component. Since you already send the `item` via `attrib` prop, you don't need the `v-model` there.

Here is a fiddle with a simple example of adding/removing stuff based on inputs.
https://jsfiddle.net/z11fe07p/437/

Also note that in case you refresh the page, all the data will be lost because vue is not meant for persiting data.